# Kicad - Change add unconnected/unnamed trace to an existing net

Tags: kicad

I have a complicated guard ring of sorts that surrounds a network of pads and traces. This guard ring is/was connected to the GND net. I had to make so changed and reload the net list. As a result the guard ring traces were orphaned and no were longer marked with the GND net. As a result, the router will not allow me reconnect the trace ring to GND. There would be considerable work to redraw all these traces.

Is there a way to apply a net to an unconnected net of traces that is not part of an existing net?

The red circle in the image below indicate where I am trying to create a connection between the net with no name around the pads on Col7 and the GND net around Col8.

[image: Red circle shows where I would like make a connection]

Comment: If you had a screen shot it would help, but you should be able to just start a trace on ground and draw it over to the guard ring.  It will violate your drc but that may not matter to you.

Comment: Yes, that was my plan if I couldn't find a proper solution.

Comment: Added image for clarification.

Comment: I think the correct way is probably to make a symbol/footprint for it.  Now that that ship has sailed I don't know another way than to turn off drc.  The problem is that every trace is assigned to some net name and I don't think you can edit that from layout.

Comment: Hasn't the guard ring got properties that you can edit? Shouldn't one of those properties be a netname? I don't know kicad but every PCB tool I've used of late has that feature.

Comment: The net of a specific trace segment does not seem to be editable in Kicad. Kicad infers the net from the pads the trace is connected to. If the trace is not connected to any pad it is given the default net of 0.

Answer (score 4):

I found a workaround of sorts.

1. Disable DRC influence on routing (I selected "Highlight collisions" from "Routing options" dialog)
2. Create a trace segment to connect the two nets
3. Save the file and close **pcbnew**
4. Reload the pcb file. **pcbnew** will update all the segments to the connect net.

Answer (score 0):

In three steps (in kicad 4.0.6 anyway):

1. Disable DRC influence on routing (Preferences->General->Options->Enforce design rules when routing)
2. Create a trace segment to connect the two nets
3. Tools->Netlist->Rebuild Board Connectivity

(I won't comment on concepts like inductance or that just labeling it GND won't magically keep it at a uniform voltage. :-)